# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with HWE stack - No GUI / GNOME Desktop Manager wont start after running "Software Updater" on Dell Laptop

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, xorg, lts, hardware-enablement-stack

Dell Laptop with a recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with HWE-kernel.
Laptop has a Intell integrated GPU and an nVidia discrete GPU.

On install from Live USB, I said "yes" to install any proprietary drivers, which in turn created a MOK signature for SecureBoot.

But as far as I am aware, it is not using any nVidia proprietary drivers and used nouveau open source drivers, like this screenshot below ( which is **NOT** exactly the screenshot I had but just a look-alike as I can't run X11 at the moment, but I remember this is what I saw as I was contemplating on trying out the proprietary drivers ) :

[image]

Furthermore, I seem to recall that it was actually using the integrated Intel GPU for X11 instead of the discrete nVidia GPU. Now I don't have anymore proof of this, except that when I was doing things like `lspci -vv`, I was only seeing Intel as a "VGA compatible controller", etc. ... and hence, was contemplating on trying out the proprietary drivers.

uname :

```
Linux 5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 14 00:32:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsb-release :

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
```

After a few days using the laptop, when I was doing `'sudo apt-get update'` and `'sudo apt-get upgrade'`, it did mention something about some changes were "kept back".

Next, installed `mesa-utils` from CLI via :

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

`/var/log/apt/history.log` for today shows ( replaced by username with xxxxxx ):

```
Start-Date: 2022-01-26  09:11:02
Commandline: apt-get install mesa-utils
Requested-By: xxxxxx (1000)
Install: mesa-utils:amd64 (8.4.0-1build1)
End-Date: 2022-01-26  09:11:03
```

Then from GNOME Desktop, I ran "**Software Updater**", this icon :

[image]

When ran, it offered to do a "Partial Upgrade", which I then clicked on the button "Partial Upgrade" which is where things got broken after a reboot. On hindsight, I should have tried to figure out what the command line equivalents it was about to do, but too late. It also did remove packages that it says are no longer used ( mostly .386 packages )

Anyway, after a reboot, I do not get a GUI and I only have a terminal ( Ctrl-Alt-F1...F9 ). I don't even have wifi / networking enabled.

This question being posted here in the forum is being done on another laptop with the log files copied from problem laptop in question shown here.

I would hate having to re-install from Live USB, so I am asking if there is a way to "undo" what "Software Updater" / dpkg did ?

Looking around at what happened, I found these in `/var/log/dpkg.log` :

```
2022-01-26 09:53:20 startup archives unpack
2022-01-26 09:53:21 upgrade linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:21 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:21 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:21 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:21 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:21 startup packages remove
2022-01-26 09:53:21 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-27-generic:amd64 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:21 remove linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-27-generic:amd64 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:53:21 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-27-generic:amd64 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:21 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-27-generic:amd64 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:22 status config-files linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-27-generic:amd64 5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:22 startup archives unpack
2022-01-26 09:53:22 upgrade nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 470.57.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:53:22 status half-configured nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 470.57.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:22 status unpacked nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 470.57.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:22 status half-installed nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 470.57.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status unpacked nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:53:23 install linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 <none> 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:23 install libgcc1:amd64 <none> 1:10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status half-installed libgcc1:amd64 1:10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status unpacked libgcc1:amd64 1:10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
2022-01-26 09:53:23 startup packages configure
2022-01-26 09:53:23 configure libgcc1:amd64 1:10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 <none>
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status unpacked libgcc1:amd64 1:10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status half-configured libgcc1:amd64 1:10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status installed libgcc1:amd64 1:10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
2022-01-26 09:53:23 configure nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status unpacked nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status half-configured nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status installed nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status triggers-pending initramfs-tools:all 0.136ubuntu6.6
2022-01-26 09:53:23 configure linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:23 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:26 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:26 status triggers-pending linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:26 configure linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:53:26 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:26 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:26 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:26 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:53:26 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
2022-01-26 09:53:26 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
2022-01-26 09:53:26 trigproc initramfs-tools:all 0.136ubuntu6.6 <none>
2022-01-26 09:53:26 status half-configured initramfs-tools:all 0.136ubuntu6.6
2022-01-26 09:53:34 status installed initramfs-tools:all 0.136ubuntu6.6
2022-01-26 09:53:34 trigproc linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:53:34 status half-configured linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:53:48 status installed linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 startup packages remove
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-gl-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-gl-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-gl-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-gl-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-gl-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-gl-470:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-encode-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-encode-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-encode-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-encode-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-encode-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-encode-470:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-decode-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-decode-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-decode-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-decode-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-decode-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-decode-470:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libx11-6:i386 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libxcb1:i386 1.14-2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libxdmcp6:i386 1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libbsd0:i386 0.10.0-1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libglvnd0:i386 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libglvnd0:i386 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libglvnd0:i386 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libglvnd0:i386 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libglvnd0:i386 1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libglvnd0:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-gl-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-gl-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-gl-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-gl-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-gl-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-gl-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-common-470:all 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-common-470:all 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-common-470:all 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-common-470:all 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-common-470:all 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-common-470:all <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-compute-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-compute-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-compute-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-compute-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-compute-470:i386 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-compute-470:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-encode-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-encode-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-encode-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-encode-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-encode-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-encode-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-decode-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-decode-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-decode-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-decode-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-decode-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-decode-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed nvidia-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove nvidia-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured nvidia-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed nvidia-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.9.1-1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files nvidia-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed nvidia-utils-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-extra-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-extra-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-extra-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-extra-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-extra-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-extra-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libxau6:i386 1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libxext6:i386 2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libxext6:i386 2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libxext6:i386 2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libxext6:i386 2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libxext6:i386 2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libxext6:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed nvidia-settings:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove nvidia-settings:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured nvidia-settings:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed nvidia-settings:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status triggers-pending gnome-menus:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status triggers-pending desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.24-1ubuntu3
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status triggers-pending mime-support:all 3.64ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files nvidia-settings:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed libxnvctrl0:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove libxnvctrl0:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured libxnvctrl0:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed libxnvctrl0:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files libxnvctrl0:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status not-installed libxnvctrl0:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed nvidia-compute-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove nvidia-compute-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured nvidia-compute-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed nvidia-compute-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status config-files nvidia-compute-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status installed nvidia-kernel-source-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 remove nvidia-kernel-source-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-configured nvidia-kernel-source-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:24 status half-installed nvidia-kernel-source-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status config-files nvidia-kernel-source-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status not-installed nvidia-kernel-source-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status installed screen-resolution-extra:all 0.18build1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 remove screen-resolution-extra:all 0.18build1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured screen-resolution-extra:all 0.18build1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-installed screen-resolution-extra:all 0.18build1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status config-files screen-resolution-extra:all 0.18build1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status not-installed screen-resolution-extra:all <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 remove libx11-6:i386 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured libx11-6:i386 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-installed libx11-6:i386 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status config-files libx11-6:i386 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status not-installed libx11-6:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 remove libxcb1:i386 1.14-2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured libxcb1:i386 1.14-2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-installed libxcb1:i386 1.14-2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status config-files libxcb1:i386 1.14-2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status not-installed libxcb1:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 remove libxdmcp6:i386 1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured libxdmcp6:i386 1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-installed libxdmcp6:i386 1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status config-files libxdmcp6:i386 1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status not-installed libxdmcp6:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 remove libbsd0:i386 0.10.0-1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured libbsd0:i386 0.10.0-1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-installed libbsd0:i386 0.10.0-1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status config-files libbsd0:i386 0.10.0-1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status not-installed libbsd0:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 remove libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-installed libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status config-files libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 remove libxau6:i386 1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured libxau6:i386 1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-installed libxau6:i386 1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status config-files libxau6:i386 1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status not-installed libxau6:i386 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 startup packages configure
2022-01-26 09:54:25 trigproc mime-support:all 3.64ubuntu1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured mime-support:all 3.64ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status installed mime-support:all 3.64ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 trigproc gnome-menus:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured gnome-menus:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.36.0-1ubuntu1
2022-01-26 09:54:25 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
2022-01-26 09:54:25 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.9.1-1 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:25 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.9.1-1
2022-01-26 09:54:26 status installed man-db:amd64 2.9.1-1
2022-01-26 09:54:26 trigproc desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.24-1ubuntu3 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:26 status half-configured desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.24-1ubuntu3
2022-01-26 09:54:26 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.24-1ubuntu3
2022-01-26 09:54:26 startup packages purge
2022-01-26 09:54:26 purge libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:26 status config-files libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:26 status not-installed libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:26 purge nvidia-compute-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:26 status config-files nvidia-compute-utils-470:amd64 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:26 status not-installed nvidia-compute-utils-470:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:26 purge nvidia-settings:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:26 status config-files nvidia-settings:amd64 470.57.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
2022-01-26 09:54:26 status not-installed nvidia-settings:amd64 <none>
2022-01-26 09:54:26 startup packages configure
```

`Xorg0.0.log` shows

```
[ 10247.573] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2
... snip ...
[ 10247.575] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" ModulePath extended to "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 10247.575] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" setting /dev/dri/card1 as PrimaryGPU
[ 10247.575] (--) PCI: (0@0:2:0) 8086:9a60:1028:0a81 rev 1, Mem @ 0x6134000000/16777216, 0x4000000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00004000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[ 10247.575] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:25a2:1028:0a81 rev 161, Mem @ 0x8e000000/16777216, 0x6000000000/4294967296, 0x6100000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00003000/128
[ 10247.575] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 10247.575] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 10247.576] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 10247.576]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.0.0
[ 10247.576]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[ 10247.576] (II) Applying OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" to /dev/dri/card1
[ 10247.576]    loading driver: nvidia
[ 10247.781] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 10247.781] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 10247.781] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 10247.781] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[ 10247.781] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[ 10247.781] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 10247.781] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[ 10247.781] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[ 10247.781] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 10247.781] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[ 10247.781] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[ 10247.781] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 10247.781]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 1.0.16
[ 10247.781]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 10247.781]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[ 10247.781] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 10247.781] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 10247.781] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 10247.781]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 1.20.13
[ 10247.781]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 10247.781]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[ 10247.781] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
...snip...
[ 10247.781] (II) Applying OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" to /dev/dri/card1
[ 10247.781]    loading driver: nvidia
[ 10247.985] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 10247.985] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 10247.985] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 10247.985] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[ 10247.985] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[ 10247.985] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 10247.985] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[ 10247.985] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[ 10247.985] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 10247.985] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[ 10247.985] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[ 10247.985] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 10247.985]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 1.0.16
[ 10247.985]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 10247.985]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[ 10247.985] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[ 10247.985] (II) Unloading nouveau
[ 10247.985] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 0)
... snip...
[ 10247.985] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Mon Jan 28 23:25:58 2019 -0500
[ 10247.985] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[ 10247.985]    RIVA TNT            (NV04)
[ 10247.985]    RIVA TNT2           (NV05)
[ 10247.985]    GeForce 256         (NV10)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce 2           (NV11, NV15)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce 4MX         (NV17, NV18)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce 3           (NV20)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce 4Ti         (NV25, NV28)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce FX          (NV3x)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce 6           (NV4x)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce 7           (G7x)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce 8           (G8x)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce 9           (G9x)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce GTX 2xx/3xx (GT2xx)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce GTX 4xx/5xx (GFxxx)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce GTX 6xx/7xx (GKxxx)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce GTX 9xx     (GMxxx)
[ 10247.986]    GeForce GTX 10xx    (GPxxx)
[ 10247.986] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[ 10247.986] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[ 10247.986] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[ 10247.986] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[ 10247.986] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -2
[ 10247.986] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -2
[ 10247.986] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[ 10247.986] (II) modeset(1): using default device
[ 10247.986] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[ 10247.986] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[ 10247.986] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[ 10247.986] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[ 10247.986] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 10247.986]    compiled for 1.20.13, module version = 0.0.2
[ 10247.986]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[ 10247.986] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -2
[ 10247.986] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[ 10247.986] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[ 10247.986] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[ 10247.986] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[ 10247.986] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[ 10247.986] (EE) 
[ 10247.986] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[ 10247.986] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 10247.986] (EE) 
[ 10248.008] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get back GNOME Desktop / GUI running again.

When I ran `ubuntu-drivers devices`, it said something like "Manual Install true".

I then ran:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```

... to install the proprietary nvidia drivers, which appears to have re-installed all the packages that were removed by the **Software Updater** / dpkg command executed by it, including some of the i386 packages that were removed by dpkg.

After a reboot, now I get the GUI back.

Now post-inspection, I have moved to a proprietary driver running and I don't appear to be using nouveau drivers anymore :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In this instance you need to install NVIDIA kernel dkms. The operating system uses dkms and modules through the kernel. I have shared next the link to the download of the file for the NVIDIA kernel dkms.

[https://packages.debian.org/sid/nvidia-kernel-dkms#:~:text=NVIDIA%20binary%20kernel%20module%20DKMS%20source.%20This%20package,for%20any%20new%20kernel%20headers%20that%20are%20installed](https://packages.debian.org/sid/nvidia-kernel-dkms#:%7E:text=NVIDIA%20binary%20kernel%20module%20DKMS%20source.%20This%20package,for%20any%20new%20kernel%20headers%20that%20are%20installed).

Since you are using Ubuntu which is basically a derivative of Debian.
You should be able to follow the below instructions as follows and it resolve your issue. Make sure you select the Code Name Repository for the files you need to download and install or update your repository to the accurate version so way you can just execute the following instead of having to download and install the files manually.

I would suggest that you install aptitude by doing the following.

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Then install the NVIDIA kernel dkms and what ever other source package you need for the device you have from NVIDIA. I will list the source location of where to obtain the driver if you do not have the correct one already downloaded.

After you install aptitude if you do not have it already installed execute the following commands to add the needed drivers and modules to your system so way they may be found along with the others upon launching X11 or startx.

Here is the needed command to execute and install using aptitude which will automatically install the dependencies required to resolve your issue.

```
sudo aptitude install nvidia-graphics-drivers nvidia-kernel-dkms
```

You will need to make sure that you have updated your repository to include the non-free to be able to install the needed software.

To edit the repository you would need to either use software or discover in the OS or manually edit the repository in shell of the file /etc/apt/sources.list and add the non-free to your sources after the main contrib non-free.

I have included a link to repository managment for further instruction on this if need be.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

If you have any questions or need further clarity please feel free to respond. I will do my best to clarify.

Regarding further support please feel free to reach out to the community that maintains this project linked as follows.

https://salsa.debian.org/nvidia-team/nvidia-graphics-drivers

Let me know if you need further assistance. :)

Comment: There's no need to use Debian packages because the Nvidia drivers are available in the official Ubuntu repositories. Ditto for aptitude. This answer is absurdly complex and not applicable to Ubuntu. Methods for Debian are seldom applicable to Ubuntu or the other way around. You should have read the other answer before.