# Multiple monitors : Black screen with blinking cursor and GNOME Desktop login only shows after switching console

Tags: 20.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, xorg, login-screen

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS HWE
- Dell Laptop with integrated Intel GPU and Discrete nVidia GPU
- Dual monitor ( Laptop monitor + Desktop monitor via HDMI from laptop )
- Configured display to "Join Display" between the two monitors

Ever since this : [Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with HWE stack - No GUI / GNOME Desktop Manager wont start after running "Software Updater" on Dell Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389318/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-with-hwe-stack-no-gui-gnome-desktop-manager-wont-start-af/1389327#1389327)

... when I reboot, I see:

- GRUB menu
- Then the Dell logo ( either after pressing `Enter` or waiting for it to just start Ubuntu )
- Then the screen output flickers ( off then on ) 2 or 3 times
- Then a blank screen with a blinking cursor at the top left of the screen

At this point, I thought that the boot failed to start Ubuntu, but if I switch to console 2 ( `Ctrl-Alt-F2` ) then back to console 1 ( `Ctrl-Alt-F1` ), then the GNOME login screen  is started ... as in it it looks like the login screen only starts **after** I switch back back to console 1 *( That is, just the purple background colour first and then the login GUI after about 1 to 2 seconds  )*.

Furthermore, I see the following logs in `/var/log/apport.log`, which corresponds to about the time I do the reboots:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 1349) Sat Jan 29 10:58:04 2022: called for pid 987, signal 6, core limit 0, dump mode 2
ERROR: apport (pid 1349) Sat Jan 29 10:58:04 2022: not creating core for pid with dump mode of 2
ERROR: apport (pid 1349) Sat Jan 29 10:58:04 2022: executable: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (command line "/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/125/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3")
ERROR: apport (pid 1349) Sat Jan 29 10:58:04 2022: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 1349) Sat Jan 29 10:58:05 2022: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash

ERROR: apport (pid 1348) Sat Jan 29 11:04:23 2022: called for pid 978, signal 6, core limit 0, dump mode 2
ERROR: apport (pid 1348) Sat Jan 29 11:04:23 2022: not creating core for pid with dump mode of 2
ERROR: apport (pid 1348) Sat Jan 29 11:04:23 2022: executable: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (command line "/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/125/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3")
ERROR: apport (pid 1348) Sat Jan 29 11:04:23 2022: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 1348) Sat Jan 29 11:04:23 2022: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring

ERROR: apport (pid 1388) Sat Jan 29 11:06:34 2022: called for pid 1043, signal 6, core limit 0, dump mode 2
ERROR: apport (pid 1388) Sat Jan 29 11:06:34 2022: not creating core for pid with dump mode of 2
ERROR: apport (pid 1388) Sat Jan 29 11:06:34 2022: executable: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (command line "/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/125/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3")
ERROR: apport (pid 1388) Sat Jan 29 11:06:34 2022: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 1388) Sat Jan 29 11:06:34 2022: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring

ERROR: apport (pid 1369) Sat Jan 29 11:22:08 2022: called for pid 1022, signal 6, core limit 0, dump mode 2
ERROR: apport (pid 1369) Sat Jan 29 11:22:08 2022: not creating core for pid with dump mode of 2
ERROR: apport (pid 1369) Sat Jan 29 11:22:08 2022: executable: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (command line "/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/125/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3")
ERROR: apport (pid 1369) Sat Jan 29 11:22:08 2022: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 1369) Sat Jan 29 11:22:08 2022: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what combination gives this behaviour, but not sure why that is happening.

Basically, it has to do with what is the **Primary Display**, as shown here :

[image]

The above screenshot shows that :

- Display (1) is my laptop dispay
- Display (2) is my desktop monitor display ( connected via HDMI from laptop )
- Primary Display is the desktop monitor

With the above combination, I get a blank screen with a blinking cursor at the top left as described in the question on reboot and I see the GUI ( actually, I think the GUI only starts as there is a delay ) when I switch console to any other ( say two via `Ctrl-Alt-F2` ) then back to console 1 ( `Ctrl-Alt-F1` ).

Now if I change the settings so that my **Primary Display** is my laptop monitor, like the screenshot below :

[image]

.. then when I reboot, the Gnome login screen shows correctly ( without me doing `Ctrl-Alt-F2` then `Ctrl-Alt-F1` ). There is still a bit of flicker in the beginning though.

Also confirmed that in this setup ( **Primary Display** is laptop monitor ), there are no crash entries in `/var/log/apport.log`.

I also do not see this behaviour if I close the laptop lid so that I only work on the desktop monitor ... but I now keep the laptop lid open as I get lower bandwidth with my wifi with the laptop lid closed.

*( 95+ Mbps with laptop lid open vs ~15 Mbps with laptop lid closed )*.

Comment: Added a comment at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1811023 with link to this page. User PJSingh5000 in that bug report used the exact same trick with Ctrl-Alt-F2 then Ctrl-Alt-F1 that I did.

Comment: did not work for me, Ubuntu22, laptop + 2 monitors, laptop display set as main, still sometimes I get black screens(